# JsonProvider Requires FSharp.Core 2.3.5

Tags: ubuntu, f#, f#-data, paket

I'm trying to run the standard example for `CsvProvider` example on XUbuntu. But I get an error that says `JsonProvider` is missing the dependency for `Fsharp.Core 2.3.5`. So, I try to install it locally with `paket` (I'm using Atom and Ionide). But it says that that package doesn't exist. Not sure what to do here.

**The code I'm trying to run:**

```
#r "packages/FSharp.Data/lib/portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

type Stocks = CsvProvider<"./data/MSFT.csv">

let msft = Stocks.Load("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT")

// Look at the most recent row. Note the 'Date' property
// is of type 'DateTime' and 'Open' has a type 'decimal'
let firstRow = msft.Rows |> Seq.head
let lastDate = firstRow.Date
let lastOpen = firstRow.Open

// Print the prices in the HLOC format
for row in msft.Rows do
  printfn "HLOC: (%A, %A, %A, %A)" row.High row.Low row.Open row.Close
```

**The error I'm getting:**

```
The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider' reported
an error: The type provider constructor has thrown an exception:
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=2.3.5.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of
its dependencies
```

**The nuget package I'm trying to install:**

```
source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
nuget FAKE
nuget FSharp.Data
nuget FSharp.Core
nuget FSharp.Core.Open.FS30 2.3.5 //<- this is the line that fails.
```

**Error Message When I Run `sudo mono .paket/paket.exe install`**

```
Paket failed with:
    Couldn't get package details for package
    FSharp.Core.Open.FS30 2.3.5 on https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.
```

**Where I saw that that should be a good package to install**

```
https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/165
```